# Swift: synchronising presentation of data in tableview return of JSON data

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm just starting to play with pulling data from a web service, and therefore the issues of timing and asynch operations.   I've currently  got a an IBAction that both initiates the getting/processing of the JSON data and the presentation, via storyboard segue, of the view controller.  Not surprisingly the table VC is ready before the data is returned/processed.  A better option would probably be to use the IBAction to get/process the data and then launch the segue from code, but as a learning process I'm interested if there is a 'preferred' way of doing this via the storyboard and synchronising the two processes.

A couple of ideas I've been playing with that could be made to work, but feel wrong, are:

1. null the datasource before getting new data, and then in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection do a nasty loop that checks for the presence of a valid data source.
2. do similar to 1 but using a delegate or notification to alert the tableView delegate methods when the data is available.  Again this should work, but it stills involves an inelegant waiting loop

I'm sure there must a better way of doing this, so can anybody give me a few pointers so I can go and research it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you as developer to estimate how long the response from the web service will take (neither should you). Therefore delaying the display of the tableview or its containing controller will make the interface look unresponsive. That's not good. Apple could think your app is broken and not approve you.

You will need to display a 'loading' message as soon as possible. Some strategies:

Keep the dataSource null/with 0 items until the data is loaded. `UITableView` has a property called `backgroundView` that you can use to display which you can use to display a loading message.

You can also just hide the `UITableView` and show a `UIActivityIndicatorview` on top that you later hide when the data is loaded (and the table view has been made visible)

Comment: Couple of good pointers.  Thank you @Juan.  Agree about not just leaving the it appearing to be doing nothing - I was always going to put in some kind of progress indicator.